# Как работать с DirectX в Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, qtcreator, directx

Попробовал создать проект в QtCeratore в Ubuntu с графической библиотекой  DirectX .

Увы почему-то не вышло.

вот  мои действия :

```
sudo apt-get install cabextract // качаем библиотеку для работы с виндовскими файлами 

wget http://www.kegel.com/wine/winetricks // качаем винишко

sh winetricks directx9   // устанавливаем 9 диретИКС
```

попробовал по стандартному `/usr/lib/` в папке библиотек найди библиотеку DirectX, у вы не нашёл. Только есть екзешник в директории `/home/comp/.cache/winetricks/directx9`

Как работать с DirectX в Ubuntu ?

Есть какой-то бракобобёр [DXVK](https://github.com/doitsujin/dxvk) НО все знают что всё что связанно с вулканом не доступно нормальному мужику.

Comment: DirectX — это чисто виндовый API... так что ответ где-то между «ни как» и «настроить кросс сборку приложений под win и запуских через вино»...

Comment: @Zat-Zer _«настроить кросс сборку приложений под win и запустить их через вино»_ я даже не подползу к таким умениям ;_; **кросплатформенность это просто жуть**

Comment: на самом деле это не так уж сложно, но грабли разбросаны на каждом шагу, так что даже тем, кто это уже делал описывать это со всеми «если» и «может быть» ни сколько не хочется... единственная болей-менее серьёзная проблема, которую я вижу — не совсем понятно, как прикрутить SDK к этому всему комплекту... но в общем ИМХО если даже не знаешь, с чего начать в такой постановке задачи, то лучше действительно заняться чем-то другим... и ещё конечно, можно просто поставить вндовую IDE под вином...

Comment: Наверное щас лучше присматриваться к `Vulkan API`.

Comment: @BeastWinterwolf  я поначалу хотел (так как работаю в ubuntu) в линуксе через opengl.  Но увы как мы знаем **в линуксе есть всё, но увы всё криво**

Comment: @timob256 очень субъективное утверждение. я бы с вами поспорил, но это не подходящее место для дискуссий.

Comment: @BeastWinterwolf **я бы с вами поспорил, но это не подходящее место для дискуссий** - увы согласиться с вами не могу :3  **давайте я создам комнату в чате** и я по теме изложу те проблемы с которыми столкнулся в opengl и какие инструменты мне нужны для работы (и чего я в сумме пытаюсь достичь )

Comment: @timob256 у меня нет большого желания вас переубеждать, просто поймите, что кроссплатформенность - это не когда всё везде как в Windows. В каждом монастыре свои правила и то что вы называете "через жёпу" на самом деле лишь иное представление того, как это должно быть, ведь понятие "удобство" субъективно. Как бы вы не любили directx, он проприетарный и это перечёркивает все его плюсы.

Comment: @BeastWinterwolf я не спорю минусов у него много. Просто дело в том что он чуть дружелюбнее чем  opengl. _увы когда не явлешься гением в сфере математических наук то "дружелюбность" библиотек либо АПИ становиться важным_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

не совсем ответ но всё таки то как я стал действовать.

- поставить виртуальную машину (VirtualBox)
- установить Windows 7 в виртуальной машине
- установить в Windows 7, SDK directX (DXSDK_Jun10.exe)

---

*Да это костыль (при этом требующий большого объема памяти "как жёсткого диска так и **оперативной** памяти "), но пока это единственный вариант.*

Comment: Актуальный DirectX уже давно входит в состав обычного Windows SDK и не распространяется отдельно. Использовать DXSDK_Jun10.exe в 2020 не имеет большого смысла.

Comment: @user7860670  можно пожалуйста скинуть ссылку как с ним работать, а то я не нашёл :(

Comment: @user7860670 извините конечно за мои ответы но увы в своей жизни, я получаю **больший** результат если работаю **от пративного то бишь от себя** , оп сему и такие ответы :3

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directx-sdk--august-2009-